# Could Not Load File Or Assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have below two class libraries.

- ClassLibrary1 (.NET framework v4.8)
- ClassLibrary2 (.NET standard v2.0)

I have to give reference of **ClassLibrary2** in **ClassLibrary1**.
When I am giving reference of **ClassLibrary2** in **ClassLibrary1**, I am getting runtime error as below :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

When I am trying to add reference of `System.Runtime (v6.0.0)` in **ClassLibrary1**, I am getting compile time errors as below.

```
The type 'xyztype' found in both 'mscorelib' and 'System.Runtime v6.0.0'
```

What i have tried so far :

- Added **NETStandard.Lib** (netstandard) NUGET
- Added `<Reference Include="netstandard"><Private>True</Private></Reference>` in **ClassLibrary1.csproj**
- Added `System.Runtime` package in **ClassLibrary1**

So how can i get out from this?

How to use **ClassLibrary2** in **ClassLibrary1** ?

Comment: Can you please share a full [mre]?

Comment: What kind of reference did you make in the project file? You must be using package references (or project reference) as required by the modern NuGet approach, not a file reference which won't work in most of the cases.